# How to slipstream Windows 8 Pro Pack?

Tags: windows-8, windows-media-center, slipstream

Another query that might take some time to get answered... As of now, AFAIK the Pro/Media Center Pack can only be downloaded via the "Add features" option in Windows 8.

1. Is there an offline installer available? If not, what if we need to reinstall once the free offer period has passed?
2. In any case, is there a way to slipstream what's downloaded into the Windows 8 (Pro) install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files are already included ion the Pro. Mount the Install.wim with DISM and use this command to upgrade the edition:

```
Dism /Image:C:\mount /Set-Edition:ProfessionalWMC
```

Comment: Thanks! 1) So when I use the "Add features" option, it downloads nothing since the files are already present? 2) Also, if I do this and then install using the slipstreamed version, can I activate using the Pro key as before? 3) Where do I enter the Media Center key then? 4) Will the Media Center key work even after the free offer period is over?

Comment: 1.) yes, the files are included
2,3,4.) I have no idea. Try it out. If nothing works, install it the normal way (Pro first and use the "Add features" option to install the Media Center)

Answer (score 0):

If you have your key, I would assume that you would have to readd your key and then you can redownload the media center pack stuff via Windows Update.

Comment: The idea of [slipstreaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slipstream_(computing)) is to apply updates, packs, and patches during the install.